# Unable to connect to a server socket in UWP

Tags: c#, sockets, uwp

I've coped and pasted the sample available on MSDN on sending data between two devices using TCP sockets and I keep getting the "**no connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it**"

Client:

```
try
{
    //Create the StreamSocket and establish a connection to the echo server.
    Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocket socket = new Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocket();

    //The server hostname that we will be establishing a connection to. We will be running the server and client locally,
    //so we will use localhost as the hostname.
    Windows.Networking.HostName serverHost = new Windows.Networking.HostName("localhost");

    //Every protocol typically has a standard port number. For example HTTP is typically 80, FTP is 20 and 21, etc.
    //For the echo server/client application we will use a random port 1337.
    string serverPort = "7777";
    await socket.ConnectAsync(serverHost, serverPort);

    //Write data to the echo server.
    Stream streamOut = socket.OutputStream.AsStreamForWrite();
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(streamOut);
    string request = "test";
    await writer.WriteLineAsync(request);
    await writer.FlushAsync();

    //Read data from the echo server.
    Stream streamIn = socket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(streamIn);
    string response = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    //Handle exception here.            
}
```

Server:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //Create a StreamSocketListener to start listening for TCP connections.
                StreamSocketListener socketListener = new StreamSocketListener();

                //Hook up an event handler to call when connections are received.
                socketListener.ConnectionReceived += SocketListener_ConnectionReceived;

                //Start listening for incoming TCP connections on the specified port. You can specify any port that's not currently in use.

                await socketListener.BindServiceNameAsync("7777");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Handle exception.
            }
        }

        private async void SocketListener_ConnectionReceived(StreamSocketListener sender, StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
        {
            //Read line from the remote client.
            Stream inStream = args.Socket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(inStream);
            var request = await reader.ReadLineAsync();

            //Send the line back to the remote client.
            Stream outStream = args.Socket.OutputStream.AsStreamForWrite();
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outStream);
            await writer.WriteLineAsync(request);
            await writer.FlushAsync();
        }
```

Can anyone please tell me what am missing here? 
I've added the required capabilities and used two PCs to run this and still no luck :(

Comment: Your server is listening on a different port than your client is trying to connect. Also you should check your firewall settings to make sure the ports are open

Comment: No I have set both the server and the client to listen to port 7777, i just copied the code from msdn. It was the first thing i did when i get the error, that is to change the port number.

Comment: Did you run the server and client on the same machine? If so, please run the server and client on the different machine, then it should work. MSDN also has explained this: [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780593#enable_loopback_for_network_access](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780593)

Comment: @user3159792 Have you solved your question? If you have any other concern regarding this issue, please feel free to let me know.